# How to preserve BindingSource EndEdit() revert changes?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

I have simple details-edit form.

Data is read from Database. DataAdapter fills DataTable and Dataset
I have created BindingSource (bs) and bound all controls to bs

Before saving to database bs.EndEdit() is called (in order to reflect all changed controls values in datasource)

All works great, except scenario when there are errors caused by constraints (eg column cant be NULL, or unique value is expected).

In this case bs.EndEdit() causes exception (what is OK) but **also revert all changes** (what is not OK to me...). So I end up in the situation when Im loosing all data entered by user (giving no chance to fix problem)

I must be doing something wrong - can someone please advise how to properly handle such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, the BindingSource's underlying data object must implement IEditableObject:

Ref MSDN #1:

> When the EndEdit method is called, all pending changes are applied to
> the underlying  data source.
>
> This method has no effect unless the objects contained by the data
> source implement  the IEditableObject interface.

Ref MSDN #2:

> IEditableObject Interface Definition Namespace: System.ComponentModel
> Assembly: System.ComponentModel.dll Provides functionality to commit
> or rollback changes to an object that is used as a data source.

Cheers